# How can I do xfail in Protractor as we do in pytest

Tags: jenkins, jasmine, protractor, karma-jasmine, pytest

Using Protractor/Jasmine conjunction automation framework I want to run test suite. When my Jenkins job runs I do not want to fail my job if any test case fails.

Pytest in python provides @pytest.mark.xfail feature to mark expected failures and this does not impact the jenkins job.

Is there any such feature in Protractor which can mark test cases as expected to fail?

I saw xit and xdescribe features but it skips the test case rather then expected failure

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the point of having the test cases as part of your Jenkins job if you don't want the results of the tests to affect the job?  If you just want to execute the tests and record the results without affecting (what I assume is) your build job, you may want to do so in a separate job.

Comment: Ultimately, I want that my test cases should impact jenkins job but for time being when test cases are in development state and product builds are not very stable I want to xfail test cases.
Once things are stable, I will remove xfail